# Spring Boot unit test with SpringSecurity and Mock

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

Currently I have several unit tests that's working correctly.
In my unit test, on init, I have included the following code:

```
@Mock
private UsersServices usersServices;

@InjectMocks
private UsersController usersControllers;

@Before
public void init() {
  this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(usuariosController)
                            .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
                            .setControllerAdvice(new UsuariosControllerAdvice(logService)).build();
}
```

this worked great, but some authorizations annotations, like `@PreAuthorize` are ignored. (In my WebSecurityConfig, I already added the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` annotation.

So, after some time, I found the following code:

```
@Mock
private UsersServices usersServices;

@InjectMocks
private UsersController usersControllers;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

@Before
public void init() {
  this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders
      .webAppContextSetup(wac)
      .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
      apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
      .build();
}
```

and now, the authorization annotations (`@PreAuthorize`) works, but the `UsersServices` mock don't. When I call my controller method on unit tests, the real `UserServices` was called, not the mock.

Here is a unit test that mock a `UserServices`:

```
when(usersServices.getUserAvatar(anyString())).thenReturn(
    CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Optional.empty()));

MvcResult result = mvc.perform(
    get("/api/users/avatar/{login:.+}", "mock.user")
        .header("Authorization", testHelpers.buildJwtToken("USER")))
        .andReturn();

    mvc.perform(asyncDispatch(result))
       .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
```

without the `standaloneSetup`, the real `userServices.getUserAvatar` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your `WebApplicationContext` is not aware of your `UsersController` with mocked `UsersServices`. To fix this you have two options:

The first option is to use

```
@MockBean
private UsersServices usersServices;
```

instead of:

```
@Mock
private UsersServices usersServices;
```

This will add mocked bean into application context so that the Spring is aware of it and, thus, will use it instead of a real one.

The second option is to set your controller directly inside `WebApplicationContext` manually. This option should not be "tried at home", but can be a workaround for cases when you do not have `@MockedBean` because of the old spring version:

```
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = wac.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory;
registry.removeBeanDefinition(beanId);

//create newBeanObj through GenericBeanDefinition

registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanId, newBeanObj);
```

Comment: tks! tried the first option, and everything seens to be ok! I'm using the latest version of Spring